# My Ubuntu 16.04 is taking long time on every bootup

Tags: 16.04

After upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, in startup it shows `/dev/sda8: clean, 451307/12025856 files, 32421229/48102656 blocks` which makes Ubuntu take some time to load.

20 slowest boot processes: `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20`:

suraj@suraj-Inspiron-3420:~$ systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20
         13.937s apparmor.service

```
     13.376s plymouth-start.service

     11.953s plymouth-read-write.service
     11.436s NetworkManager.service
     10.853s thermald.service
     10.316s dev-sda8.device
     10.232s ModemManager.service
     10.226s gpu-manager.service
      9.866s accounts-daemon.service
      9.529s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.200s polkitd.service
      3.910s grub-common.service
      3.688s rsyslog.service
      3.657s avahi-daemon.service
      3.595s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      3.309s console-setup.service
      3.084s winbind.service
      3.074s nmbd.service
      2.958s samba-ad-dc.service
      2.956s binfmt-support.service
```

Comment: The message you see is not an error but just information that a quick file system check (actually it normally just verifies the journal integrity which is *really* quick) as been performed and no errors were found. To find out what is really taking much time to load on boot, you can use the `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` command, which shows the 20 slowest boot processes. Please [edit] your question to add its output.

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814))? Thanks.